# Setup project windowsForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-project

I 've create a Setup for My project , when I execute it works and every things seems better, but when I copy this setup and launch in other PC there was an error, The application doesn't work cause of an icon which I have added before into a button (It can't found her emplacement).
In the Setup procedure , I have added the icon into the folder of Setup  to may solve this issue but, the problem persist again.

Any idea, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't have now the message Error exactly but when I click for details in the error , It show me the emplacement of the image (D:/Downloads/Print.png ) who can't found it

Answer (score 2):

Did you write the setup yourself? If so, make sure you include your image in your build.

VS -> Solution Explorer -> Click File -> take a look a Properties -> Build Action

Comment: Build Action should be set to Copy always or copy if newer

Comment: Yes, I've include the image and build it